# Do not upload to document library automatically

Tags: document-library

Is there a way to turn off, or disable, automatic document upload on a document library?  When I upload a document to a doc library (using the Upload Document form) SharePoint automatically uploads it.  It shows the associated content type columns form - allowing you to set the column values.  A message of "The document was uploaded successfully.  Use this form to update the properties of the document" is displayed on this form.  Clicking the "Cancel" button on this form does not cancel the upload.  Is there a way to not upload the document automatically?  I would rather upload the document when "Save" is clicked on the document property form.  Is this possible?

Comment: but the workflow doesn't seem to be working on click of Cancel button. The workflow status is "starting" on click of cancel button. Any ideas/thoughts how to make a workflow working?

Comment: Did you intend to post this answer as a comment to another question? If you want, you can flag it for mod attention so that it may be converted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the "update the properties of the document" form opens you get a "Delete Item" option at the top before you click on Save. This way you can "delete" the uploaded document before closing the dialog button incase you do not wish to proceed with the document.

However, out of the box there is no way you can disable the upload before the document properties form is loaded.

Programmatically, it can be possible but it wont be a good approach to address any business requirement by changing the behaviour of the document upload form which is there by "application design" of the SharePoint platform.

Rather, if possible you can use a simple webpart to upload the document in a document library and expose the page to the users where this document is uploaded. They can choose to rename and do other modifications before the "actual" upload is initiated.

Answer (score 4):

This is a real problem if required properties are not completed and the user clicks cancel.  Defeats the purpose of required properties!  The only simple way to do this I believe is to delete the document using a SharePoint workflow.  Set the workflow to execute when a document is added and if any of the required fields are not completed, delete the document.  It's nice to send an email to the user to notify them that the document was not uploaded successfully.